# Twitter and Facebook buttons alignment

Tags: html, css, button, alignment, social-networking

## Context

I want to display Twitter and Facebook buttons on my new site.

But I get an issue with alignment.

[image]

## Code

**[html](/questions/tagged/html):**

```
<span id="social">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="guillaumgregoir">Tweet</a>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://csstooltip.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</span>
```

**[css](/questions/tagged/css):**

```
#social {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 24px;
}

div.fb-like {
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: There must be more CSS and/or JavaScript than that in play here. The CSS you've provided can not accomplish what is being seen in your image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove margin top from your css - but you could use floats like below:

```
<div>
<div style='float:left;'>
--put a button here
</div>
<div style='float:left;'>
--put a button here
</div>
<div style='clear:both;'>
</div>
</div>
```